# How to search more than one word in a sentence using javascript

Tags: javascript

The Code below search a particular word **(best)** in a sentence and return true or false depending on the result.

Now I need to upgrade to allow it search for **mulptiple** words Eg. **"site, all, world"**

```
var myString = 'Stackoverflow is the best site for all developers in the world';

var multiple_Word = 'best';
var a = new RegExp('\\b' + multiple_Word + '\\b');
alert (a.test(myString)); // false
```

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you're asking. What's the expected input and output?

Comment: `best|site|world` is what you are looking for.Although on @jonrsharpe has a point, perhaps is has to contain all words?

Comment: Hi JonrSharpe. I need it to return true if any of the three words are found in the sentence or false if non of those three words exist in a sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your code and change it to a function.

```js
var myString = 'Stackoverflow is the best site for all developers in the world';

function search(input){
  var a = new RegExp('\\b' + input + '\\b');
  return a.test(myString)
}

console.log(['site', 'all', 'world', 'blah blah'].some(e=>search(e)))
```

You can use join as in comment you mentioned you want to match one these.

```js
var myString = 'Stackoverflow is the best site for all developers in the world';
const words1 = ['best', 'site', 'random'];

let reg = `\b${words1.join('|')}\b`
let regex = new RegExp(reg)

console.log(regex.test(myString))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a good regex resource here:  **https://regex101.com/**
Added `blah` to demonstrate.

```js
var myString = 'Stackoverflow is the best site for all developers in the world';

var multiple_Word = 'best|BLAH|world';
var a = new RegExp('\\b' + multiple_Word + '\\b');
alert (a.test(myString)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Array#join with `|`

```js
const str = 'Stackoverflow is the best site for all developers in the world';

const words1 = ['best', 'site', 'random'];
const words2 = ['will', 'fail', 'always'];

const a = new RegExp('\\b' + words1.join("|") + '\\b');
const b = new RegExp('\\b' + words2.join("|") + '\\b');

console.log(a.test(str));
console.log(b.test(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of doing this with `includes()`

```js
let words = ["the","best","world"];
let words2 = ["the","best","world","apple"];
var myString = 'Stackoverflow is the best site for all developers in the world';
function checkWords(str,words){
  for(let word of words){
    //if the word in words arr doesnot exist is str it will return false
    if(!str.includes(word)) return false
  }
  //if false is not return in loop it means all words exist is str so return true 
  return true;
}
console.log(checkWords(myString,words));
console.log(checkWords(myString,words2));
```